# Cannot determine dimensions of status bar int WP8.0 app on WP8.1 HD/FHD device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, statusbar

I have a problem which I cannot overcome by any means. I've spent already 2 days on it without success, so I've finally decided to ask you guys.

What I want:
I need to know the exact dimensions of status bar when running my WP 8.0 app on WP 8.1 phone with HD or FHD resolution.

Why I need it:
I use DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid to render graphics. DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid always uses full screen as a render target. I don't want to draw under status bar, so I use the status bar dimensions to trim the viewport correctly.

What is the problem:

Here is how it works on WP 8.0 phone:
The status bar has constant dimensions in logical pixels:
In portrait mode they are 480px x 32px. 
In landscape mode they are 72px x 800px(15:9 aspect ratio) or 72px x 853px(16:9 aspect ratio)

Here is how it works on WP 8.1 device:
On devices with 15:9 aspect ratio the behaviour is the same as on WP 8.0 device.

On 16:9 devices things get more complicated.

In portrait mode WP 8.1 does not use 32px for status bar. Instead WP 8.1 uses some unspecified amount of pixels for status bar and some some unspecified amount of pixels for black bar at the bottom of the screen. The sum of these amounts equals 32px.

In landscape mode WP 8.1 does not use 72px for status bar. Instead WP 8.1 uses some unspecified amount of pixels for status bar and some some unspecified amount of pixels for black bar at the right/left edge of the screen. The sum of these amounts equals 72px.

The relation of size of status bar to size of aforementioned black bar is a mystery to me. The relation is different on FHD device than on HD device.

Anybody has clue?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the height of the StatusBar in Windows Phone WinRT.

```
private void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var transform = LayoutRoot.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
    Point coords = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
    double height = coords.Y;
}
```

LayoutRoot is the main control (usually a `Grid`) inside the `Page` root.

Comment: always returning 0 in my case

Comment: Is your Page full screen? With overlapping StatusBar on your content?